# accidental shorthand for module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node.js and JavaScript is sometimes confusing for a beginner like me. Experimenting with mocha and export, I made a typoo in the source typoo.js:

```
module.exports,trial = function() {
    console.log('trial')
}
```

Please note the comma "," after `module.exports,` It would have been a "." if I did not accidentally typed the comma.

Frankly I was happy with the result. It works as I wanted which is not to seperate the export from the function definition. **How come the comma works as I do not expect but meets my intensions?**

```
const blah = require('../../../typoo');
trial()
```

mocha logs "trial"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning to an undeclared identifier in loose mode creates a global variable (I call it [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)). That's why what you have works, because

```
module.exports,trial = function() {
    console.log('trial')
}
```

uses the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), where each side of that is an operand. Both expressions are evaluated, so you have

```
module.exports
```

as its own expression, and

```
trial = function() {
    console.log('trial')
}
```

as its own expression.

You almost certainly don't want to create a global; instead, do what you were trying to do, make `trial` a module export. If you want to be more concise, you can drop the `module.` part:

```
exports.trial = function() {
    console.log('trial')
};
```

(Also note I've added the missing semicolon.)

And then of course to use it:

```
const blah = require('../../../typoo');
blah.trial();
```

...or any of the variations on that theme, such as:

```
const trial = require('../../../typoo').trial;
trial();
```

...or

```
const { trial } = require('../../../typoo');
trial();
```

Also recommend using strict mode instead of the default loose mode by adding

```
"use strict";
```

to the top of your module. In strict mode, assigning to an undeclared identifier is the error it always should have been. :-)

Comment: That makes sense T.J. Thanks for avoiding my bad practice. I wonder why you persist on adding the ";" though. Is leaving out ";" considered a bad practice too?

Comment: @otembajelle: Leaving off the `;` means that the JavaScript engine's parser has to add it to the token stream for you. Automatic semicolon insertion is an *error correction mechanism*, correcting the error of leaving out a required `;`. You can choose to rely on it if you like, there are some who do. I don't like leaving the door open to silly mistakes, such as: https://jsfiddle.net/so5xhcmm/